# Google App Engine Channel API with iOS client?

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, channel-api

I'm looking into using the Channel API to push messages to my iOS client. I haven't completely wrapped my head around it, but the only way would be to use a hidden UIWebView that triggers an Objective-C method.

Would this work? To have a hidden UIWebView listening to channel messages? How would the web view be notified of new messages by the channel? How would I trigger an Objective-C method when a new message is received, such as an alert saying "You've received a new message."?

Are there any downsides to this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm doing the opposite.  I'm using Urban Airship to send iOS notifications to my iOS app, which is really an iOS wrapper around a UIWebView.

GAE Channels aren't particularly robust in my experience, I've noticed messages not get sent, especially when you have to re-establish a connection.  I wonder if the UIWebView connection will get disconnected when the app goes to the background.

Comment: Just curious, how is reliability with Urban Airship? How long does it take for notifications to be received? I'm using Pushwoosh and on average it takes over 10 seconds for pushes to be received.

Comment: Seems fast, nearly instant, under a second usually.  But I haven't scaled up yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing what you are asking. There are two things you need to be able to do: make calls from Objective-C into the UIWebView, and get events from the UIWebView to call back in to Objective-C. To do the first you call UIWebView's "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString" method. To call back into Objective-C, you register a web view delegate, and then in the "shouldStartLoadWithRequest" method you look for a "fake" protocol (e.g. "js-callback" or something like that) so that in your javascript you navigate an iframe to "js-callback:informationForObjectiveCToOperateOn". This blog post explains the procedure: http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/.